# How do I convert 60mph to light years per second using scientific notation?

Tags: unit-of-measure

I tried to follow along with this units video (https://youtu.be/hQpQ0hxVNTg) and convert 60 miles per hour to light years per second. I don't get the same answer as the video does. I feel really dumb!

[image]

I just try to multiply through? and get:
$$
\frac{60ly}{60*60*5.9*10^{12}sec} = \frac{1ly}{60*5.9*10^{12}sec} = \frac{1ly}{3.54*10^{14}sec}
$$
or $3.54*10^{-14}$ light years per second

please halp!

Comment: You typed $5.9^{12},$ not $5.9 \cdot 10^{12}.$

Comment: I fixed the typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video is wrong. I have no clue where they arrived at that number.

First - note that $\frac{1}{x} \neq x$ unless $x = \pm 1$. That is,

$$ \frac{1}{3.54 \cdot 10^{14}} \neq 3.54 \cdot 10^{-14}.$$

Instead, that is equal to $2.824 \cdot 10^{-15}$ which is the correct value you should arrive at. See [this Wolfram query](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=60%20mph%20to%20light-years%20per%20second). I also verified this on my calculators.

Comment: This answer looks very different than the video's approximation! The video number expands to 0.0000000000093ly/s while this one is 0.000000000000002824ly/s Also thank you for correcting the mistake I made while trying to move my scientific notation to the numerator.

Comment: I'm still a little bit confused on how $\frac{1}{3.54*10^{14}}$ is somehow equivalent to $2.824*10^{-15}$? Or are they not equivalent? Also doesn't the Wolfram query say 2.835 instead of 2.824?

Comment: Just punch it in your calculator and you'll see.

Comment: ah thanks again! I guess Wolfram might be using a slightly different constant for the light years to miles fraction? Just guessing. That might be the difference between Wolfram and us.

Comment: No - just more decimal digits used